# How to create Upload files in laravel 5.1?

Tags: database, laravel-5.1

I'm new to `Laravel 5.1`

Can you guys help me on how to upload files like `docx`, `PDF` or `image` to store it in the database using `Laravel 5.1` ?

I browsed a lot of tutorials but not in `Laravel 5.1` I'm trying it myself but it didn't work.

> NotFoundHttpException in
>
> C:\Loucelle\ **_\
>   _**\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php line 161:

Can you help me by giving any sample codes?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the routes and controller for handling the upload

Comment: one thing i want point out is you can't save the real file in database, rather, you upload to a folder and store file names in table

Comment: @Digitlimit ohww...okay sir i will create a path for uploads file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Route:

```
Route::post('uploadFile', 'YourController@uploadFile');
```

Your HTML blade:

```
<form action="{{ url('uploadFile') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Your Controller:

```
public function uploadFile()
{
    //get the file
    $file = Input::file('file');

//create a file path
$path = 'uploads/';

//get the file name
$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

//save the file to your path
$file->move($path , $file_name); //( the file path , Name of the file)

//save that to your database
$new_file = new Uploads(); //your database model
$new_file->file_path = $path . $file_name;
$new_file->save();

//return something (sorry, this is a  habbit of mine)
return 'something';
}
```

**Useful resources** (these links *may expire*, so they are only here for *reference*):

[Laravel Requests (like Inputs and the such)](http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests)

[File Upload Tutorial that helped me when I started](http://clivern.com/how-to-create-file-upload-with-laravel/)

Comment: thank you sir...i've tried this and edit a little bit and it works sir.. ^^ thank you ^^